# Spring boot app access to Azure Keyvault secret

Tags: spring-boot, azure-keyvault

I am trying to set up a Spring boot app to connect to Azure keyvault and fetch secrets.
I have looked across various code samples, but cannot get one to work.

There are no errors related to the keyvault library itself, but the Spring bean does not get initialized with the property fetched from the secret.

I am using Spring boot 2.7.3 and the keyvault starter lib is 4.2.0. This is what I referred to get my property config.
https://microsoft.github.io/spring-cloud-azure/4.2.0/reference/html/appendix.html#_azure_key_vault_secrets_properties

```
application.yml
------------
spring:
  cloud:
    azure:
      keyvault:
        secret:
          enabled: true
          endpoint: https://uri/
          credential:
            client-certificate-path: <path to pem file>
            client-id: <client-id>
          profile:
            tenant-id: <tenant-id>


build.gradle
--------------
implementation 'com.azure.spring:spring-cloud-azure-starter-keyvault-secrets:4.2.0'


Spring bean
-------------

@Configuration
@Getter
@Setter
public class AKVProperties {
 
 
  @Value("${MYAPP-DB-LOGIN-PASSWORD}")
  private String dbPassword1;
  ...

Exception at startup:
----------------------
Error creating bean with name 'AKVProperties': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'MYAPP-DB-LOGIN-PASSWORD' in value "${MYAPP-DB-LOGIN-PASSWORD}"
```

Answer (score 0):

- I think the issue is with `application.yaml` file. you have to set your config settings under `property-sources:` .
- This is the  `application.yaml` I used where everython is set under the `property-sources:`

```
spring:
  cloud:
    azure:
      keyvault:
        secret:
          property-sources:
            - credential:
                client-id: <CLIENT ID>
                client-secret: <CLIENT SECRET>
              endpoint: '<END POINT>'
              profile:
                tenant-id: <TENANT ID>
```

- Here I have retriving the secret like this

```
@Value("${secret}")  
private String secret;
```

and then I am just console logging them .

Output:

[image]

Keyvault:

[image]

Comment: I tried this, but I still get the same result. I do not see any errors, except for Spring complaining that the bean could not be initialized. Can you share the gradle dependencies for Azure keyvault in your application? Also what version of spring are you using?

Comment: my spring boot version : 3.0.0

Comment: the spring-cloud-azure.version is 6.0.0-beta.4

Answer (score 0):

My answer focuses on newer versions so starting with version 4.3.0, it will work.

Reference [link](https://microsoft.github.io/spring-cloud-azure/4.3.0/reference/html/index.html#all-configurable-properties) for additional properties you may need.

> DO NOTE : You need minimum **SPRING 3.X.X** and **JAVA >=16**

Your **application.properties** would look like below.

```
spring.cloud.azure.keyvault.secret.property-source-enabled=true
spring.cloud.azure.keyvault.secret.property-sources[0].endpoint=
spring.cloud.azure.keyvault.secret.property-sources[0].profile.tenant-id=
spring.cloud.azure.keyvault.secret.property-sources[0].credential.client-id=
spring.cloud.azure.keyvault.secret.property-sources[0].credential.client-secret
```

Your pom.xml file should contain following dependencies

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-starter-keyvault-secrets</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Now, you should be able to use Azure Key Vault secrets in your properties and yaml files. For example: `spring.security.user.password=${your-vault-key}`

Additionally, they can also be imported into code by using

```
@Value("${database.secret.value}")
private String mySecret;
```

Here **your-vault-key** and **database.secret.value** are just for example you would  use your vault secret key names which you would have created on Azure.

If anyone need steps for Azure's side of implementation, let me know I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the use-case to create a sql-server bean after reading the secrets from Azure key-vault.

The below steps should help you setup the app.

First, you have to create a `Configuration` class that can initialize a `SecretClient` object for us.

```
@Configuration
public class AzureSecretClientConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecretClient createSecretClient() {
        return new SecretClientBuilder()
                .vaultUrl("https://app-kv.vault.azure.net/")
                .credential(new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build())
                .buildClient();
    }

}
```

Next step will be to use this configuration object to fetch the secrets from `key-vault` based on `secret-key-name`

A `sql-server configuration` can now use the `AzureSecretClientConfiguration` object to fetch secrets from azure key vault.

I have the below variables defined in `applicaiton.properties`. Please note how each variable refers to the key-name in azure key-vault.

```
# SQL Server Properties
spring.datasource.url.azure.key=sql-server-metastore-db-uri
spring.datasource.username.azure.key=sql-server-metastore-db-username
spring.datasource.password.azure.key=sql-server-metastore-db-password
```

Entries from Azure Key-Vault -
[image]

Now a `Sql Server Config` class can use the previously created `AzureSecretClientConfiguration` SecretClient to fetch and create its own config object. Please refer the `getSecret()` function below -

```
@Configuration
public class SqlServerKeyVaultConfig {
    @Autowired
    AzureSecretClientConfiguration azureSecretClientConfiguration;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.url.azure.key}")
    private String sqlServerDbUriSecretName;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.username.azure.key}")
    private String sqlServerUsernameSecretName;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.password.azure.key}")
    private String sqlServerPasswordSecretName;

    @Bean
    public String sqlServerDbUrl() {
        System.out.println("Data-source url " + sqlServerDbUriSecretName);
        return getSecret(sqlServerDbUriSecretName);
    }

    @Bean
    public String sqlServerUsername() {
        return getSecret(sqlServerUsernameSecretName);
    }

    @Bean
    public String sqlServerPassword() {
        return getSecret(sqlServerPasswordSecretName);
    }

    private String getSecret(String secretName) {
        return azureSecretClientConfiguration.createSecretClient().getSecret(secretName).getValue();
    }

}
```